# How can I create a link to display entries filtered by a channel field?

Tags: search, filter

I need to create links to display job listings by 1) job type (a channel field) **or** 2) salary range (also a channel field). The salaries are single integers.

I also need to display the search above the results, for example, "Listings: Executive Jobs," or Listings: $75k to $85k Jobs."

I've struggled with this all day and can't find a solution. :(

Is this something that can be done natively within EE or do I need something like Low Search?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

[image: A visual that explains it all]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `search:field_name` parameter to filter the entries. For job type, `search:job_type="=[JOB TYPE]"` for exact match.

For salary range, its needed if its numeric field so that you can use parameter like `search:numeric_field=">=20"` and `search:numeric_field="<=20"`

See [documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) here.